# design NFA which accepts specific length of strings

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, nfa

Im looking forward to design a FA which accepts some kind of string that accept some A and B.

First a string which the number of A is five more times higher than B.

i mean  `L={w∈{A,B}* and (nA(W)-nB(W) mod 5=0)`

And also a FA which accept different number of character in a string:

```
L={A^n B^m C^k | n,k>0 and m>3}
```

I design some FAs But they did not work perfectly on this complicated strings.

Any help on how should i design this ?

Comment: Here's a simple regular expression for your second case: `AA*BBBBB*CC*`. The first case would be most simply implemented using a pushdown automaton (state machine + stack) rather than an FSM, though.

Comment: (In fact, I believe it isn't doable with an FSM on a string of unbounded length as the number of states required would grow to infinity, but I'd have to work through the derivation to be sure.)

Comment: Actually, `nA(W)-nB(W) mod 5=0` seems to imply that `nB(w)` could be greater thatn `nA(w)` as well

Comment: so,can i design a FA for them or not? i stuck in this !!!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your questions are confusing as the english text doesn't agree with the mathematical formula. I will try to answer to these four questions then:

- A language which consists of string over {a,b} that the number of a (= #a(w))
  is five times as the number of b ( #b(w)),
  `L = { w in {a,b}* : #a(w)>#b(w) and #a(w)=#b(w)mod5 }`

  This cannot be done by an NFA. The proof is simple by using the pumping lemma (P.L) with the string a^pb^5p, where p is the constant of P.L.
- For the language: `L={w∈{A,B}* : (nA(W)-nB(W)) mod 5=0}` that you wrote,
  you can do it with an DFA that consists of a cycle of 5 states.

  The transitions are, if you read a go clockwise if you read b go counter-clocwise. Choose at random one state to be initial state and the same state will be the final state.
- For the language L={A^n B^m C^k | n,k>0 and m>3}, it should be easy to find out
  if you read L as `L=A(A)* B(B)* c^4(C)*`
- For the language that accepts different number of character in the string (let's say over a,b). The language should be `R={ w in {a,b}* : #a(w) not equal #b(w)}`

  This language again it cannot be recognized by an NFA. If this language was regular (recognzied by an NFA) so would be this language:

  `L=a*b* intersection (R complement)`. The language L is `{a^n b^n/ n non-negative integer}`.

  The language L is the first example of most books when they speak about languages that are non-regular.

Hopefully, you will find this answer helpful.